# Hosted CMS - Based On Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, content-management-system, drupal-7

I just want a little clarification concerning hosted CMS like shopify.com, solidshops.com (I learnt Shopify runs on Ruby on Rails) so let me be specific about hosted CMS based on Drupal: www.buzzr.com, www.drupalgardens.com and www.pagebuild.net etc..

What I want to know is

1. Do they use the Multi-Site feature in Drupal to automatically creates all those 1000s of sites they host when a user sign up?
2. Do they create those 1000s of sites as sub-sites (otherwise known as subdomains)?
3. Do they use a different way other than the Multi-Site in Drupal?

Comment: Hm.. [link]http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ too is a good place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how Buzzr and Drupal Gardens work, but there is some info about Pagebuild in this [Pagebuild Case Study](http://drupal.org/node/993166). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Acquia is a drupal based CMS hosting service.

http://www.acquia.com/